# creating a query from multiple tables in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an issue with designing a query I could do with some help with. I have three tables (there is more but these should do for this):

- Game Review
- Reviewer
- Game

I need a query that will only select games that the reviewer has not reviewed (if that makes any sense).

Any ideas? It's to populate a box on an add-review form so that when a reviewer has been selected, the next drop-down will only show games that have not been reviewed yet by that reviewer

Further info: game review and reviewer contain a `reviewer` ref field, game review and game contain a `game` ref field

```
SELECT Game.*, [Game Review].*
FROM Game LEFT JOIN [Game Review] ON Game.[Game Ref] = [Game Review].[Game Ref*]
WHERE [Game Review].[Reviewer ref*] IS NULL;
```

i think this doesnt work because im getting the data from a text box in the form ie

```
[Forms]![FRM_Add_review_form]![reviewercombo]
```

Comment: This sounds like homework.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sample schema: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e2e8

Comment: @DanMetheus Its part of some work but wasn't specifically asked for, I have the whole database built and just thought this would be a nice addition to help prevent duplicate errors on the form, to be honest I'm trying a few different things now on paper but I haven't learnt too much SQL and am just asking for help as to where to start with this query

Comment: @mellamokb more of a select query im looking for , the schema is all set up and working fine do you want me to post the  relationships or anything ?

Comment: @user1652319 If you post the table structures, at least the relevant column names plus some sample data it would be useful.  I think that's what mellamokb was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some asumptions because I don't have all the field names, but it would be something like this:

```
SELECT Game.*, GameReview.*
from Game
Left Join GameReview 
on Game.GameID = GameReview.GameID
WHERE GameReview.Review IS NULL
```

Comment: sorry ive added the code to the question as it wasnt formatting properly down here ... thanks for your help

Comment: I hope your field name doesn't really have an asterisk in it?!?  Aside from that, using a field from a form shouldn't be a problem.  Just join the Reviewer table and then add something like this to the end of the SQL: "AND Review.ReviewerName = '" & [Forms]![FRM_Add_review_form]![reviewercombo] & "'"